# magento 1.9 doesn't show "state" dropdown in checkout

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm running magento 1.9.2.0 and I configured the config options to ask for a "state" for Italy, but when I try to buy the state isn't actually required.

Here's some screenshots:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIfiY.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIWkZ.png]

This looks like a magento bug to me. How can I fix it?

Comment: I update my answer with an example sql insert script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to populate the `directory_country_region` table in database.

You may run something like this :

```
INSERT INTO 
  `directory_country_region` 
  (`region_id`, `country_id`, `code`, `default_name`) 
VALUES
  (NULL, 'IT', 'IT-52', 'Toscana'), // example with ISO_3166-2 REGION code
  ...
  (NULL, 'IT', 'IT-BO', 'Bologna'); // example with ISO_3166-2 PROVINCE code
```

Little explanation :

- `region_id` is auto-incremented
- `IT` is ISO-3166-2 `country_id` for Italy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:IT
- `code` is a internal value for identify region in system, in best pratices it's good to use the iso region code, you can retrieve the list of the 20 regions of Italy in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:IT#Regions. You can provide the 110 provinces of Italy too, in this case use the province code instead of region code, You can retrieve the list of 110 provinces code in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:IT#Provinces
- `default_name` is the ISO_3166-2 region|province name. You can update the name later with the Magento translation process

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: For sure, you are right. I just pasted the links in answers to not clutter the stream but a complete response is always preferable. Thank you for your advice. If I have time today I will try to update my answer.

Comment: Hi, I already have provinces in directory_country_region table. the only difference is the code: I have "BO" instead of "IT-BO". maybe that's the reason? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the example from Nolweig and outside source I have created script to import all Italian regions.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

umask(0);
Mage::app('');

// set up array containing regions to be added (region_code => region_name)
$new_regions = array(
   'AG' => 'Agrigento',
   'AL' => 'Alessandria',
   'AN' => 'Ancona',
   'AO' => 'Aosta',
   'AR' => 'Arezzo',
   'AP' => 'Ascoli Piceno',
   'AT' => 'Asti',
   'AV' => 'Avellino',
   'BA' => 'Bari',
   'BT' => 'Barletta-Andria-Trani',
   'BL' => 'Belluno',
   'BN' => 'Benevento',
   'BG' => 'Bergamo',
   'BI' => 'Biella',
   'BO' => 'Bologna',
   'BZ' => 'Bolzano',
   'BS' => 'Brescia',
   'BR' => 'Brindisi',
   'CA' => 'Cagliari',
   'CL' => 'Caltanissetta',
   'CB' => 'Campobasso',
   'CI' => 'Carbonia-Iglesias',
   'CE' => 'Caserta',
   'CT' => 'Catania',
   'CZ' => 'Catanzaro',
   'CH' => 'Chieti',
   'CO' => 'Como',
   'CS' => 'Cosenza',
   'CR' => 'Cremona',
   'KR' => 'Crotone',
   'CN' => 'Cuneo',
   'EN' => 'Enna',
   'FM' => 'Fermo',
   'FE' => 'Ferrara',
   'FI' => 'Firenze',
   'FG' => 'Foggia',
   'FC' => 'Forlì-Cesena',
   'FR' => 'Frosinone',
   'GE' => 'Genova',
   'GO' => 'Gorizia',
   'GR' => 'Grosseto',
   'IM' => 'Imperia',
   'IS' => 'Isernia',
   'SP' => 'La Spezia',
   'AQ' => 'L\'Aquila',
   'LT' => 'Latina',
   'LE' => 'Lecce',
   'LC' => 'Lecco',
   'LI' => 'Livorno',
   'LO' => 'Lodi',
   'LU' => 'Lucca',
   'MC' => 'Macerata',
   'MN' => 'Mantova',
   'MS' => 'Massa-Carrara',
   'MT' => 'Matera',
   'ME' => 'Messina',
   'MI' => 'Milano',
   'MO' => 'Modena',
   'MB' => 'Monza e della Brianza',
   'NA' => 'Napoli',
   'NO' => 'Novara',
   'NU' => 'Nuoro',
   'OT' => 'Olbia-Tempio',
   'OR' => 'Oristano',
   'PD' => 'Padova',
   'PA' => 'Palermo',
   'PR' => 'Parma',
   'PV' => 'Pavia',
   'PG' => 'Perugia',
   'PU' => 'Pesaro e Urbino',
   'PE' => 'Pescara',
   'PC' => 'Piacenza',
   'PI' => 'Pisa',
   'PT' => 'Pistoia',
   'PN' => 'Pordenone',
   'PZ' => 'Potenza',
   'PO' => 'Prato',
   'RG' => 'Ragusa',
   'RA' => 'Ravenna',
   'RC' => 'Reggio Calabria',
   'RE' => 'Reggio Emilia',
   'RI' => 'Rieti',
   'RN' => 'Rimini',
   'RM' => 'Roma',
   'RO' => 'Rovigo',
   'SA' => 'Salerno',
   'VS' => 'Medio Campidano',
   'SS' => 'Sassari',
   'SV' => 'Savona',
   'SI' => 'Siena',
   'SR' => 'Siracusa',
   'SO' => 'Sondrio',
   'TA' => 'Taranto',
   'TE' => 'Teramo',
   'TR' => 'Terni',
   'TO' => 'Torino',
   'OG' => 'Ogliastra',
   'TP' => 'Trapani',
   'TN' => 'Trento',
   'TV' => 'Treviso',
   'TS' => 'Trieste',
   'UD' => 'Udine',
   'VA' => 'Varese',
   'VE' => 'Venezia',
   'VB' => 'Verbano-Cusio-Ossola',
   'VC' => 'Vercelli',
   'VR' => 'Verona',
   'VV' => 'Vibo Valentia',
   'VI' => 'Vicenza',
   'VT' => 'Viterbo',
);

// specify country code for new regions
$country_code = 'IT';

// specify locale
$locale = 'it_IT';

// create our core_write conection object
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

// iterate our new regions
foreach ($new_regions as $region_code => $region_name) {

    // insert region 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`region_id`,`country_id`,`code`,`default_name`) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)";
    $connection->query($sql,array($country_code,$region_code,$region_name));

    // get new region id for next query
    $region_id = $connection->lastInsertId();

    // insert region name
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `directory_country_region_name` (`locale`,`region_id`,`name`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $connection->query($sql,array($locale,$region_id,$region_name));
}

echo 'Import finished';
```